# React don't mount component until needed but don't unmount afterwards in list of components

Tags: reactjs

Say I am building an instant messaging with app with React (I'm not doing that *exactly*, but this is easier to explain). I have a sidebar with a list of conversations and, when you click one, it is shown on the right (similar to [this](https://thehackernews.com/images/-EUxmg4d_AZc/VMANFw5h2oI/AAAAAAAAhiM/5XhiQpJp3rk/s728-e100/Whatsapp-web-app.png)). I don't want to mount each conversation component until the user clicks it, but I don't want to unmount it, just hide it, when they click on another conversation. How can I do this cleanly? There will never be more than about 30 chats for any user.

Comment: display:none. But i'm not sure that is good idea. After long app running it will consume more and more memory.

Comment: It's not super clear, but is all a matter of managing states. Is it a really big app where u need redux? Cause the way u explain it context API it's enough. Explain a but better how you want to design it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the enabled conversations in an array that you use to show, and when you disable a conversation you can just add a `hidden` prop to it which you pass to the conversation and make it `return null`. This will make it not render anything but will not unmount it since you have not removed it from the array that handles the display of conversations.

example at: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-forest-59bqj

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to answer since you haven't posted the code.

But, theoretically, the best way to approach this problem is to transfer the data from your sidebar component and load it onto the right component on a per-user basis. You don't have to mount each "conversation component".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by with the boolean `hidden` property in your markup. React will render as usual and simply pass it along to the html, the browser will then simply not paint it.

```
const HideMe = ({ isHidden }) => (
  <div hidden={isHidden}>
    can you see me?
  </div>
)
```

I made an example for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-curie-t4ill?file=/src/App.js

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hidden.asp